# Pass a variable defined in a controller to a model under CodeIgniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, parameter-passing, codeigniter-2

I defined a variable in a method inside controller e.g.

```
class test extends CI_Controller {
    function tester() {
    $variable = 'value'
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this variable in my model. How is that possible?

Edit: I use CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
class your_model extends CI_Model {
    var $variable;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function set_variable($variable) {
        $this->variable = $variable;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
class test extends CI_Controller {
    function tester() {
        $this->load->model('your_model');
        $variable = 'value'
        $this->your_model->set_variable($variable); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, If I remove `var $variable;` &

`function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }` it still works. Is there any reason to use those ?

Comment: constructor - only if you need it. $variable - jjust a definition

Answer (score 2):

FYI - if you need a variable available for more then one method in a controller and/or in your model - you can set it in the 'constructor' of the class. Use **$this->** before the variable name.

```
 class Test extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct() {

 parent::__construct();

  // Set var in construct  
  $this->variable123 = 'some value 123' ;

} // end construct
```

You can now call $this->variable123 from anywhere in the class and it will be available. 
If you load a model from this class, it will be available to any method in the model.